# what is wrong with this script of mysql?

Tags: mysql

i want that these codes run automatically after 24 hours everyday ( repeatedly ), with nested if conditions

```
CREATE EVENT three  -- create your event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
  STARTS '2019-09-24 00:00:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
DO BEGIN
IF (connector.initial_invest ==30 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 0.75 
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest == 40 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 1.5
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest == 100 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 3
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest == 150 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 4.5
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest == 200 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 6
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest == 300 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 9
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest == 500 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 15
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest == 700 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 21
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest == 900 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 27
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest == 1500 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 45
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest == 2000 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 60
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest == 3000 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 90
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest == 4000 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 120
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest == 5000 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 150
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest == 10000 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 300
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest == 15000 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 450
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest == 20000 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 600
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest == 30000 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 900
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest == 40000 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 1200
ELSE UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 1500
END IF
END
```

what is the error ?

Comment: Hi :) What behaviour are you expecting and what behaviour are you seeing? Does the script above fail for some reason, or does the schedule not work the way that you expect it to?

Comment: I don't see any statement terminators or delimiters being set, null safe equals in mysql is <=> not ==

Answer (score 0):

Setting delimiters,terminators and fixing the null safe equals allows the event to syntax

```
drop event if exists e;
delimiter $$
CREATE EVENT e 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
  STARTS '2019-09-24 00:00:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
DO 
BEGIN
IF (connector.initial_invest <=>30 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 0.75 ;
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest <=> 40 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 1.5;
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest <=> 100 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 3;
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest <=> 150 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 4.5;
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest <=> 200 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 6;
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest <=> 300 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 9;
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest <=> 500 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 15;
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest <=> 700 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 21;
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest <=> 900 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 27;
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest <=> 1500 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 45;
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest <=> 2000 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 60;
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest <=> 3000 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 90;
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest <=> 4000 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 120;
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest <=> 5000 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 150;
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest <=> 10000 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 300;
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest <=> 15000 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 450;
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest <=> 20000 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 600;
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest <=> 30000 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 900;
ELSEIF (connector.initial_invest <=> 40000 ) THEN UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 1200;
ELSE UPDATE connector set connector.user_stock= connector.user_stock + 1500;
END IF ;
END $$

delimiter ;
```